# What levels should static analyzers analyze?

Tags: static-analysis, findbugs, lint

I've noticed that some static analyzers operate on source code, while others operate on bytecode (e.g., FindBugs). I'm sure there are even some that work on object code.

My question is a simple one, what are the advantages and disadvantages of writing different kinds of static analyzers for different levels of analysis?

Under "static analyzers" I'm including linters, bug finders, and even full-blown verifiers.
And by levels of analysis I would include source code, high-level IRs, low-level IRs, bytecode, object code, and compiler plugins that have access to all phases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These different facets can influence the level at which an analyzer may decide to work:

1. Designing a static analyzer is a **lot** of work. It would be a shame not to **factor this work for several languages** compiled to the same bytecode, especially when the bytecode retains most of the structure of the source program: Java (FindBugs), .NET (various tools related to Code Contracts). In [some cases](http://why.lri.fr/), the common target language was made up for the purpose of analysis although the compilation scheme wasn't following this path.
2. Related to 1, you may hope that your static analyzer will be a little less costly to write if it works on a **normalized version of the program** with a minimum number of constructs. When authoring static analyzers, having to write the treatment for `repeat until` when you have already written `while do` is a bother. You may structure your analyzer so that several functions are shared for these two cases, but the care-free way to handle this is to translate one to the other, or to translate the source to an intermediate language that only has one of them.
3. On the other hand as already pointed out in Flash Sheridan's answer, **source code contains the most information**. For instance, in languages with fuzzy semantics, bugs at the source level may be removed by compilation. C and C++ have numerous "undefined behaviors" where the compiler is allowed to do anything, including generating a program that works accidentally. Fine, you might think, if the bug is not in the executable it's not a problematic bug. But when you ever re-compile the program for another architecture or with the next version of the compiler, the bug may appear again. This is one reason for not doing the analysis after any phase that might potentially remove bugs.
4. Some **properties can only be checked with reasonable precision on compiled code**. That includes absence of compiler-introduced bugs as pointed out again by Flash Sheridan, but also [worst-case execution time](http://www.absint.com/ait/). Similarly, many languages do not let you know what floating-point code does precisely unless you look at the assembly generated by the compiler (this is because existing hardware does not make it convenient for them to guarantee more). The choice is then to write an imprecise source-level analyzer that takes into account all possibilities, or to analyze precisely one particular compilation of a floating-point program, as long as it is understood that it is that precise assembly code that will be executed.

Comment: Agreed its a shame to not share common infrastructure for a specific analysis across several languages.  It is also a shame to not share infrastructure that is common to a variety of static analyzers.  Our DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit tries to achieve both by providing infrastructure needed for a wide variety of analyzers, that is easily configured for a specific language or a specific analysis, for source programs.

Answer (score 1):

Source code analysis is the most generally useful, of course; sometimes heuristics even need to analyze comments or formatting.  But you’re right that even object code analysis can be necessary, e.g., to detect [bugs introduced by GCC misfeatures](http://isc.sans.edu/diary.html?storyid=6820).  Thomas Reps, head of GrammaTech and a Wisconsin professor, gave a good talk on this at Stanford a couple of years ago: http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~reps/#TOPLAS-WYSINWYX.